# How do I keep all query parameters intact when changing page in django?

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-pagination

I have this issue with pagination:

`<a href="{{ request.get_full_path }}{% if request.GET %}&{% else %}?{% endif %}page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>`

It works fine, but every time I click on it it adds one more ?page=1 at the end of the URL, so url looks like this after a few clicks:
example/something?query_params=5&page=1&page=1&page=1&page=1

I know why that happens, it's because I hardcoded it into URL, but I have to use get_full_path because I need other query parameters together with `page`.

So basically I want all those query params but WITHOUT page=something being added each time I change the page. I need only one `page` query parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can effectively remove the page number in the view, like:

```
class MyView(View):
    # …

    def request_get(self):
        rq = self.request.GET.copy()
        rq.pop(self.page_kwarg, None)
        return rq.urlencode()
```

then in the view, we can work with:

```
<a href="{{ request.path }}?{{ view.request_get }}&amp;page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
```

we can also make a helper function for this to include the path:

```
class MyView(View):
    # …

    def request_get(self):
        rq = self.request.GET.copy()
        rq.pop(self.page_kwarg, None)
        return rq.urlencode()

    def path_without_page(self):
        return f'{self.request.path}?{self.request_get()}'
```

and thus work with:

```
<a href="{{ view.path_without_page }}&amp;page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
```

It is however a bit of a pity that the page object itself has no access to the request object, and that thus the pager could construct such links. I personally find this one of the shortcomings of Django's pagination system.

Comment: This seems like best way there is. One question, how would you do it for a function based view FBV?

Comment: @Eliott: you process the `request` the same way (copy the `request.GET` dict, pop out the page, and urlencode it), and pass that string to the template. It is not that special for a class-based view, but likely here the power of a mixin can be used to define the logic once in a mixin, and then mix it in all sorts of views that use the template.